# ReferenceError: Cannot access uninitialized variable. Typescript, cordova, iOS

Tags: ios, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, referenceerror

Could anyone suggest please, what is going wrong ? When I build my Ionic app on Ios platform I have an error, on Android everything is ok.

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access uninitialized variable.   service.ts:31
```

At service.ts on 31 line I have class declaration..

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score -2):

**Carlos Julio**, share the complete content.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {SqlService} from "./sql.service";
import {Subscriptions} from '../models/subscriptions';

import {Platform/*, Events*/ } from '@ionic/angular';

import {Events} from './events.service';

import {UserServiceService} from './user-service.service';
/*import { BackgroundMode } from 'ionic-native';*/
import {ModelsServiceService} from './models-service.service';
import {User} from '../models/user';

import {UpdateNewProviderService} from "./update-new-provider.service";
import {LogProviderService} from "./log-provider.service";
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import {LoginProviderService} from "./login-provider.service";

import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';


//BackgroundMode.enable();

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SubscriptionsServiceService {

  //storage:Storage = null;
  //products:Array<Object>;

  products:any;
  public count = 0;
  public output;
  public checksubscription: string;

  constructor(
      private sql: SqlService,
      public platform: Platform,
      public updateNewProvider: UpdateNewProviderService,
      public userService: UserServiceService,
      public logProvider: LogProviderService,
      public http: HTTP,
      public events: Events,
      private device: Device,
      public loginProvider: LoginProviderService,
      public modelService: ModelsServiceService
  ) {

    this.products = [];
    // this.storage = new Storage();
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      this.checksubscription = this.loginProvider.rootUrl + 'checksubscription.php';


    });

  }

  addSubscription(subsc: Subscriptions){

    console.log("subsc",subsc);

    let save = 'INSERT INTO subscription (user_id, external_id, description, active, url,work_order,bu_url,iu_url,bu_url_local_path,iu_url_local_path,mu_url,mu_url_local_path,sc,server_date,date_warning,date_auth,run_warning_message,run_warning_message_time,update_method,iurl,murl,rurl,ua,status,pi,ms) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';

    console.log(save ,[subsc.user_id, subsc.external_id, subsc.description, subsc.active, subsc.url]);

    return this.sql.query(save, [subsc.user_id, subsc.external_id, subsc.description, subsc.active,
      subsc.url,subsc.work_order,subsc.bu_url,subsc.iu_url,subsc.bu_url_local_path,subsc.iu_url_local_path,
      subsc.mu_url,subsc.mu_url_local_path,subsc.sc,
      subsc.server_date,subsc.date_warning,subsc.date_auth,subsc.run_warning_message,subsc.run_warning_message_time,subsc.update_method,subsc.iurl,subsc.murl,subsc.rurl,subsc.ua,subsc.status, subsc.pi, subsc.ms]);
  }

  addNewSubscription(subsc: Subscriptions):Promise<any>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

      console.log("addNewSubscription", subsc);

      this.selectCurrentSubscription(subsc).then(d=>{

        if (undefined !== d) {

        if (d.res.rows.length>0)
        {
          let save = 'UPDATE subscription SET description =?, active =?, url =?, work_order=?,bu_url=?,iu_url=?,bu_url_local_path=?,iu_url_local_path=?,mu_url=?,mu_url_local_path=?,sc=?,server_date=?,date_warning=?,date_auth=?,run_warning_message=?,run_warning_message_time=?,update_method=?,iurl=?,murl=?, rurl=?, ua=?, status=?, pi=?, ms=? WHERE user_id=? AND external_id= ?';
          this.sql.query(save ,[subsc.user_id, subsc.external_id, subsc.description, subsc.active,
            subsc.url,subsc.work_order,subsc.bu_url,subsc.iu_url,subsc.bu_url_local_path,subsc.iu_url_local_path,
            subsc.mu_url,subsc.mu_url_local_path,subsc.sc,
            subsc.server_date,subsc.date_warning,subsc.date_auth,subsc.run_warning_message,subsc.run_warning_message_time,subsc.update_method,subsc.iurl,subsc.murl, subsc.rurl, subsc.ua, subsc.status, subsc.pi,  subsc.ms]).then(() => {

            //console.log(save ,[subsc.description,subsc.active,subsc.url,subsc.work_order,subsc.bu_url,subsc.iu_url,subsc.user_id, subsc.external_id]);

            resolve(true);
          //}).catch(err =>{reject(err)});
          }).catch(err => {


            console.log("err catch",err);
            reject(err);
          });


        }
        else
        {
          let save = 'INSERT INTO subscription (user_id, external_id, description, active, url,work_order,bu_url,iu_url,bu_url_local_path,iu_url_local_path,mu_url,mu_url_local_path,sc,server_date,date_warning,date_auth,run_warning_message,run_warning_message_time,update_method,iurl,murl,ua,status,pi,ms) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
          this.sql.query(save,[subsc.user_id, subsc.external_id, subsc.description, subsc.active,
            subsc.url,subsc.work_order,subsc.bu_url,subsc.iu_url,subsc.bu_url_local_path,subsc.iu_url_local_path,
            subsc.mu_url,subsc.mu_url_local_path,subsc.sc,
            subsc.server_date,subsc.date_warning,subsc.date_auth,subsc.run_warning_message,subsc.run_warning_message_time,subsc.update_method,subsc.iurl,subsc.murl,subsc.ua,subsc.status,subsc.pi,subsc.ms]).then(()=>{


            /*            console.log(save ,[subsc.user_id, subsc.external_id, subsc.description, subsc.active,
                                          subsc.url,subsc.work_order,subsc.bu_url,subsc.iu_url,subsc.bu_url_local_path,subsc.iu_url_local_path]);*/

            resolve(true);
          //}).catch(err=>{reject(err)});
          }).catch(err => {

            console.log("err catch",err);
            reject(err);
          });


        }

        }

      });
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Was useful if you share the complete content of service.ts because maybe the error is in a previous line affecting everything onward

Comment: This isn't an answer. Such things should go in comment.